# Combine two results in one row

Tags: sql-server

EmpID   Name    Date    Earn

1        A    7/1/2014   2

1        A    7/1/2014   4

1        A    7/2/2014   1

1        A    7/2/2014   2

2        B    7/1/2014   5

2        B    7/2/2014   5

I would like combine two results in one row as below.here is my statement but i want to find the solution to get the Total_Earn?. Thank

"SELECT EmpID, Name, Date, Sum(earn) FROM employee WHERE Date between DateFrom and DateTo
GROUP BY EmpID, Name, Date"

EmpID   Name    Date    Earn    Total_Earn

1        A    7/2/2014   3        9

2        B    7/2/2014   5        10

Comment: Can you post the columns and column types you're returning? As well as the SQL statement you're using to pull that data?

Comment: In your expected results what does 3 and 5 refer to in the 1st and and 2nd rows respectively? It looks like a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Substitute the date for whatever value you want.

```
SELECT table1.EmpID, table1.Name, table1.Date, table1.Earn, table2.Total_Earn

FROM
    (SELECT EmpID, Name, Date, Earn
    FROM yourtablename    
    WHERE Date = "2014-07-02"
    GROUP BY EmpID) table1
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT EmpID, SUM(Earn)
    FROM yourtablename
    WHERE Date <= "2014-07-02"
    GROUP BY EmpID) table2
ON table1.EmpID = table2.EmpID
```

This will perform two SELECTs and join their results. The first select (defined as table1) well select the employee ID and earnings for the specified date.

The second statement (defined as table2) will select the total earnings for an employee up to and including that date.

The two statements are then joined together according to the employee ID.

Comment: Did it not work, or is there another reason for the downvote?

Comment: Below is my statement but i not yet find the solution to get TotalEarn -                                                    SELECT EmpID, Name, Date, Sum(earn) FROM employee
WHERE Date between DateFrom and DateTo
GROUP BY EmpID, Name, Date

Comment: TotalEarn is SUM(Earn). Is that not what you want?

Comment: Total_Earn mean that the total get from DateFrom and DateTo and Earn mean that the amount of the current date. Like say in example, i select date=7/2/2014, so the Earn=5 and the total_earn=10 (7/1/2014 to 7/2/2014)

Comment: I see what you're asking, give me a second to edit my response

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want the Max date and the Sum of Earn for each employee. Assuming you want one record for each ID/Name, you would do this:

```
select EmpID, Name, Max(Date), Sum(Earn) 
from YourTableName
group by EmpID, Name
```